# What is the difference between the shutdown, halt and reboot commands?

Tags: linux, unix, shutdown, reboot

Should I be using one or the other for different things?

Comment: man halt covers the differences

Comment: have read it, just wanted clairification

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`halt` brings the system down to its lowest state, but leaves it powered on.

`shutdown` brings the system down to its lowest state, and will turn off power (soft power switch) if it can. Most computers now can do so.

`reboot` restarts the system. It brings the system down to its lowest state, then starts it up again.

Which to do depends on what you want to do.  `halt` is usually to get to a state where you can perform low level maintenance. `shutdown` is to power the system off, and reboot is to reboot it.

Comment: Whenever I use the `halt` command on Mac OS X and Linux, it completely shuts my system down.

Comment: This is slightly incorrect. `shutdown` can bring the system to any of these states, including single user mode (the default). Also, there is the `poweroff` command, turning power off (if possible).

Comment: yeah halt also completely turns my computer off ( Ubuntu server 9.04) but I normally just type halt to poweroff and reboot to restart because its shorter than the shutdown command. Any harm in that?

Comment: @loosecanon - ask your question in a separate question. :-) There is actually an issue with what you suggest, and _could_ cause data loss.

Comment: @RichHomolka about `"halt is usually to get to a state where you can perform low level maintenance"` what do you mean with that?. Thanks

Comment: @ManuelJordan it’s not really used anymore, it was used back in the days of big honkin’ Solaris boxes.  It was used to get the machine where the OS wasn’t running, whether that meant power off or drop to the equivalent of bios or whatever.

Comment: @RichHomolka thanks for the polite explanation.